# How to PHP Unset Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to unset some values from array. Array is like as below:

```
$data['total'] = Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [title] => Sub-Total [code] => sub_total [text] => Rs. 1,222 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [title] => Free Shipping [code] => shipping [text] => Rs. 0 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [title] => Free Shipping [code] => [text] => Rs. 0 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [title] => VAT (1%) [code] => tax [text] => Rs. 12 ) 
 [4] => Array ( [title] => Total [code] => total [text] => Rs. 1,222 ) 
)
```

**I managed to do it by `unset($data['total'][1])` and `unset($data['total'][2])`**

But at some point of time Array changed like below

```
$data['total'] = Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [title] => Sub-Total [code] => sub_total [text] => Rs. 1,222 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [title] => Free Shipping [code] => shipping [text] => Rs. 0 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [title] => Free Shipping [code] => [text] => Rs. 0 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [title] => Total [code] => total [text] => Rs. 1,222 ) 
)
```

So, wrong values are being unset from array.

> I want to unset values with `code` **shipping** and **tax** if present in the array.

Also i tried as below

Tried after Rizier comment: [NOT WORKING]

```
foreach($data['totals'] as $key => $sub_array) {
    if($sub_array['code'] == 'tax') {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
if($sub_array['code'] == 'shipping') {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Please assist

Comment: So you just want to filter your array and delete all subArrays where `code` is either equal to `shipping` or `tax`?

Comment: yup.. You got it right

Comment: Then you have different options how you can do it. Looping through your array with a simple loop and filter it by your condition or use `array_filter()` and apply your condition.

Comment: An answer will be helpful

Comment: Look in the duplicate. There are all options explained and how you can apply your condition to it.

Comment: Rizier ... this is not duplicate.. i tried all methods but nothing seems to work in my case.. so please assist

Comment: .What have you tried? How does your current code looks like?

Comment: each and every method in ques.. My issue is that i do not have particular key for subarray that i can unset,, those are just index ie. 0,1,2

Comment: in asked ques that you have marked duplicate with do not has sub arrays

Comment: You do not need to know the explicit keys. You can use `array_filter()` for example and do something like: `$data["total"] = array_filter($data["total"], function($subArray){return !in_array($subArray["code"], ["shipping", "tax"]);});`

Comment: Rizier, i have posted a try in ques.. is that not correct

Comment: Everything perfect, except that you need to unset the correct array: `unset($data["total"][$key]);` and NOT some other array: `unset($array[$key]);`.

Comment: SO which one is faster.. `filter_array` or posted solution

Comment: and please remove duplicate and post your comment as an aswe.. it may help someone

Comment: Choose the one which is more clearer to you. I won't reopen the question since both ways here, and even more ways, are covered in the dupe